# How do I find count of class within a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, dojo

I have the following HTML writen in [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo):

```
<div id="102_do_3_9_id_z_3" class="element_unit_index nominal out">2</div>
```

This is one example of what I can generate, but I have 20 types of elements similar to this one.

I wonder how I can get number of defined classes on one DIV, so that I get array of classes and in the array I can check if this element is not equal with 'nominal' then

```
dojo.removeClass(tmp_elm_on_div_ins_id,this._state);
```

Comment: `"dojo/dom-class"` link [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-class.html) is the module you are looking for. It has a method `contains()` to check if the dom node has a particular class. e.g `domClass.contains("someNode", "aSillyClassName")`

Comment: thanks for fast replay, but `hasClass()` i use to check when i know what class will be, in this case i need remove all other classes that is not for  example `nominal` but still i need bcs of css style `element_unit_index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the class list and iterate it you can use somehting like this:

```
var classList =$('#102_do_3_9_id_z_3').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    if (item === 'someClass') {
       //do something
    }
});
```

Another suggestion: ID cannot start with a number it's not valid html.

Comment: You can use an all-numeric id according to the HTML5 specification (anything but a space is okay).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to split the classes in an string array, just a vanilla js solution will do. Get the element as a DOM Object, and split its `class` attribute.

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var classArray = div.getAttribute("class").split(" ");

for(var i=0; i<classArray.length; i++) {
    classArray[i]; //Check what you want
}
```